# Create hyperlinks in column to address in other column

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

Is it possible to (perhaps with a hotkey) change the text in a cell in column `E` into a hyperlink to a website that is listed in column `F`.

I think that is the easiest way to create these links, and to update them if needed.

Edit: It turns out that the HYPERLINK function isn't good enough. I need to export the excel file to a .pdf, but using the HYPERLINK function results in a .pdf file without working hyperlinks. The cause seems to be the .pdf conversion first resolves all Excel formulas before converting it into a .pdf file. Therefore, the only way to create working links is to have the text in a cell become a hyperlink by doing it manually. Is it possible for a macro to do this automatically, without using the HYPERLINK function?

Comment: It is.. strange that I didn't find it while Googling for 'Excel hyperlink formula'... Thanks!

Comment: As it turns out, `=HYPERLINK()` is not good enough, please see the edit in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try Hyperlinks.Add https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx

Say cell f5 contains http://stackoverflow.com as text. The code converts it to a link that displays the original text in e5.

```
Sub ConvertToHyperlink()
With Worksheets(1)
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("e5"), _
 Address:=.Range("f5"), _
 ScreenTip:="test web site"
End With

End Sub
```